# Non recursive pell function python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def p_sequence():
    length = int(input("Sequence length: "))
    a = 0
    b = 1
    for i in range(length):
        c = 2*b+a
        a = b
        b = c
        print(b, "", end = "")
    print()
```

I'm trying to create a pell function that's non-recursive and I'm stuck. The output that I want is:

```
length = 4
Output: 0 1 2 5
```

What I get:

```
length = 4
Output: 2 5 12 29
```

I tried putting if statements in the for loop but it didn't work out either... help?

Comment: If nothing else you should print a and do it at the start of the loop not the end. I don’t understand why you couldn’t/didn’t work that out for yourself, though - just add print statements for the variables every time round the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the second value (`b` in two consecutive values `a` and `b`) after changing it, thus it will start from the third element in the sequence. Changing `print(b, "", end = "")` to `print(a, "", end = "")` and putting it right after `for i in range(length):` will yield the desired output.

Also, the line `print(b, "", end = "")` could be changed to `print(b, end=" ")`, same effect but simpler.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still new to python so I'm not familiar with everything (just yet)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're printing the wrong variable at the wrong time.  Instead consider:

```
def p_sequence():
    length = int(input("Sequence length: "))

    a, b = 0, 1

    for _ in range(length):
        print(a, end=" ")
        a, b = b, 2 * b + a

    print()
```